# Vuetify: Using Vue's Default Footer with Custom Sort

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuetify.js

I would like to utilize the :custom-sort binding while also not disabling Vue's default footer. So far, either one or the other works. Either I disable the footer and my custom sorting method works, or I lose the custom sort for pagination. Is it possible to use the the default Vue footer for datatables while also sorting using my custom method?

Here is the relevant code:

list.html (with no hide-default-table):

```
<v-data-table :headers="tableProjectHeaders" :items="projectList" :page.sync="pageNumber" :pageCount="numberofPages" :items-per-page.sync="itemsPerPage" :server-items-length="totalProjects.length" :custom-sort="customSort" :options.sync="siteOptions">
<!-- Content gets Rendered Here -->
</v-datatable>
```

I'm not sure how helpful having the code from the vue component will be, but here's what the relevant parts of the vue app look like:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    methods:{
              customSort: function (items, index, isDesc){
              // Too much code, will share upon request but not sure the nitty gritty is relevant
              return items;
              }
        },
    data(){
        return {
            ...
            pageNumber: 1,
            totalProjects: 0,
            numberofPages:0,
            siteOptions:{},
        }
       }
      });
```

Any ideas? Is this possible? Do I have to create a custom footer and manually implement the pagination? Let me know if there is any more code I can share to illuminate the issue.